# How to run nested/subquery in google sheet?

Tags: sql, arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language

SQl : select id,tod,count from new_temp where (id,count) in (select id,min(count) from new_temp group by id);

i want to run this in google sheet. How i can run this ?

[[image: DatasetResult]
[image: Resultset]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: First one is dataset and other one is result set, need to group using two columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 1, 1, 3, 1), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

---

```
=SORTN(QUERY(A2:C7, 
 "select A,B,min(C) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,B 
  order by A,min(C) 
  label min(C)''"), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but i want to run this using query and my id is in date format

Comment: @Harshkumar answer updated